# How can i get data-id value(id) store in Array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, sortablejs

how can i get id number(data-id) using JavaScript. I'm using sortable.min.js for drag & drop. i want to get the `td` ID(data-id) which is inside of `#drop` table and store it into a array(sort)?

table.html

```
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Story</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="drop" class="sortables">
            <tr>
                <td data-id="67">67</td>
                <td>this is test post for (news2)d</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-id="59">59</td>
                <td>how to use custom fonts in dja</td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
               <td data-id="51">51</td>
               <td>how can i merge two forms fiel</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Story</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="drag" class="sortables">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

script.js

```
   new Sortable(drag, {
        group: '.sortables',
        animation: 150,
    });


    new Sortable(drop, {
        group: '.sortables',
        animation: 150,
        onChange: function (e, tr) {
            sort = [];
            $("#drog").children().each(function () {
                sort.push({ 'id': $(this).data('id') })
            });
            console.log(sort)
        },
    });
```

Comment: typo `$("#drog").children()` => `$("#drop").children()`

Comment: please can you explain it how can i define it into my function because i'm beginner in JavaScript can you make a answer with update you code in my code

Comment: Change the line: `$("#drog").children().each(function () {` to `$("#drop").children().each(function () {`

Comment: yes i also try this but i getting `undefined` or empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, you have a Typo in your Selector:

```
$("#drog")
```

Should be:

```
$("#drop")
```

You can also consider the following.

```
new Sortable(drag, {
  group: '.sortables',
  animation: 150,
});

new Sortable(drop, {
  group: '.sortables',
  animation: 150,
  onChange: function (e, tr) {
    var sort = [];
    $("#drop > tbody > tr").each(function (i, row) {
      sort.push({ 'id': $("td:first", row).data('id') });
    });
    console.log(sort);
  },
});
```

Your previous code was targeting the `children` of `#drop`, which are `<TR>` elements and do not have the Data attribute.

The new code targets the 1st `<TD>` element of each row. This element has the Data attribute.

Comment: it's getting the empty array. it dose not get the ID

Comment: your code is help full `$("#drop").each(function (i, row) {` this code is work for me. thanks